# mysql - search for the exact word phrase without using regex nor rlike

Tags: mysql, regex

I have my table like this:

```
|name           |
-----------------
|Joseph Jackson |
|Aiden Chase    |
|Luke Benjamin  |
|Joseph         |
|Joseph2        |
```

If I search for the word  Joseph (`SELECT * from myTable where name="Joseph"` ) I woud get only the last result:

```
|name           |
-----------------
|Joseph         |
```

If I search for the word Jackson, I won't get any results.

That is what I DON'T want.

---

What I want is to get the records that exist in the exact word searched, for example:

if the word searched is Joseph, I woud get:

```
|name           |
-----------------
|Joseph         |
|Joseph Jackson |
```

*Notice that Joseph2 is not in the result set.

If the word searched is Jackson, I woud get:

```
|name           |
-----------------
|Joseph Jackson |
```

*But I cannot use `like '%Jose%'` (the use of like) cuz I will get Joseph2 and I want the exact word(Jose).

*If the word searched is Jose for example I shouldn't get any result, cuz Jose is not in the data (also I shouldn't get records that contain the Joseph word).

---

The only way I've found is using regex for example:

```
SELECT * from myTable where REGEXP [[:<:]]Joseph[[:>:]]     

|name           |
-----------------
|Joseph         |
|Joseph Jackson |


SELECT * from myTable where REGEXP [[:<:]]Jackson[[:>:]]

|name           |
-----------------
|Joseph Jackson |
```

I want this results but without using regex and whithout rlike, is there any way? How? thanks.

Comment: Why do you not want regexes or rlike?  What is the reason for that restriction?

Comment: I want search for accented words, and there is no way with regexes.

Comment: How are you executing this stored procedure? when/where do you enter a  name to search on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although full text as @Mihai suggests is definitely the way to go for production, if you want to do a one-off search without building extra indices you can just use `LIKE` by adding spaces around the names and search for the name including surrounding spaces;

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE CONCAT(' ', name, ' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ', 'joseph', ' %')
```

Note that this will *definitely* not use any indexes, so can be useful for admin purposes but not for a production application that cannot handle full table scans.

Answer (score 4):

This screams for FULLTEXT search

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (name);

SELECT * FROM T WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+Joseph' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a7a4/1)

Comment: @user2580401 Yes if you are on 5.6 r higher

Comment: But if I search for Joseph Jackson I get two results: Joseph Jackson and Joseph when I only wish Joseph Jackson. How to solve this? help please.

Answer (score 1):

allow your stored procedure to accept a parameter for @name then you can use the WHERE clause

```
WHERE name = @name
```